# Preventing loss of detail using "Clip Raster by Mask Layer" QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, satellite

I am using a raster file of satellite imagry as input for a 'Clip Raster by Mask Layer' process and a shape file polygon as my mask layer. Each time I run the process the output clipped layer is slightly brighter and slightly less detailed than the input.

I have checked the box for keep resolution of input raster so I was wondering if anyone has any ideas why this might be happening?

I'm using QGIS 3.12

Comment: Before and after screenshots would really help, particularly if they were zoomed in!

Comment: Have you checked from the layer properties that image is showed without contrast enhancement? Histogram of the clipped area may differ from the histogram of the whole image and stretch to min/max could change the appearance.

Comment: Hi both, sorry I haven't been able to get into my account to reply. The issue was that the clipped images were set to Stretch to MinMax under band rendering with max values which were, I assume, calculated based on the clipped images themselves.

Comment: It was simple enough to change the max values manually post clipping under: layer properties -> symbology -> band rendering. Once I work out how to set it up before clipping I'll post it here. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.